# Override page title when logged in - TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 8.7.7. with fluid_styled_content.
I want to change the the title of the login page from 'login' to 'logout' (subtitle) when the user is logged in. With TYPO3 7.6.x I used the following snippet successfully

```
[loginUser = *]
temp.mainnav.2.NO.stdWrap.override.cObject = TEXT
temp.mainnav.2.NO.stdWrap.override.cObject {
    value = subtitle
    if.value.field = uid
    ## ID of the login page
    if.equals = 22
}
temp.mainnav.2.CUR.stdWrap.override.cObject <lib.mainnav.2.NO.stdWrap.override.cObject
[global]
```

Now I have always the same title.

Comment: why do you use temp and lib with the same subparts? do you know the difference between these objects?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I changed 'lib' to 'temp' but still get always the same title.

Comment: sounds strange as a TS-condition always opens another cache variant of affected content/pages. You should inspect the resulting TS with the TSOB. Look at the final usage `page.10. ...` instead of intermediate `temp. ...` objects. And use the condition-checkboxes to toggle the evaluated condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that I don't have the solution for TS, but here is how I did for this situation. I create 2 pages, one for Login (show at any login) and the other for Logout (hide at login).

Answer (score 0):

You could use fluid in this instance:

```
<f:security.ifAuthenticated>
    <f:then>
        Logout
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        Login
    </f:else>
</f:security.ifAuthenticated>
```